# How see code-view for view controller in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, function, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

In my Xcode project, I have several view controllers in my storyboard. How can I see the code for a specific view controller?

Because each view controller will need to have different functions from the others. So, where can I write that code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, storyboard will use UIViewController for the view controllers you use.

However you can change the class used for the view controller by:

1. selecting the view controller (in Interface Builder)
2. show the identity inspector (View > Utilities > Show identity inspector)
3. Change the value in Class to "MyOwnViewController"

Where "MyOwnViewController" is the name of the UIViewController subclass that you want to use for that view controller.

Comment: I mean, where can I see the code? I'm looking in the .h and the .m. I don't see any code that has anything to do with my viewcontroller. I've added labels and other things using the interface builder. But the h/m files haven't changed. I should be able to edit what's in the view controller, not only via the interface builder, right? But I should be able to edit it's code directly. But where?

Comment: No, the design you do in interface builder doesn't impact the view controller. The view controller, as its name implies, is not the view, but it controls a view (it has a property view) and that view can be created programmatically, or in IB without code. However, you still can do both: have some view elements created in IB and others in the view controller.

Comment: @Dingredient - What do you mean by: *" I should be able to edit what's in the view controller"*? you mean add UI or add functionality such as actions, reading data, ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for the confusion. My situation is this:  I downloaded a sample project "ScareCam" from apple's dev site. It uses the camera to detect faces in real time. Looking over the functions in the .m, I see variables like "faceRect" and "bounds." I wanted to find out which variable hold the actual coordinates of the detected face. So, using the interface builder, I created a label, which I'd like to layer on top of everything for the moment, to display the value of those variables... In the code, I can't find my label, so how can I set it to show a variable?

Comment: You should add an IBoutlet in the view controller and link it to the label in interface builder.

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the View Controller you want to see the code
2. Go to the Assistant editor

[image]

It's on the upper bar to the right.

Answer (score 3):

The "Show the Assistant editor" venn diagram icon on the top right did it for me.
Xcode Version 6.4

Answer (score 2):

Select the storyboard in the navigator, right click and select 'Open As'. You should see 2 options 'Interface Builder - Storyboard' or 'Source Code' - select the Source Code option should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You subclass each `UIViewController` to add unique functionality. The implementation of `UIViewController` is private to Apple, the interface is described in it's documentation.

Comment: But where is the code? I commented on sch's answer too. I should be able to edit what's in the view controller, not only via the interface builder, right? I should be able to edit it's source code directly. But where? Its not in .h or .m...

Answer (score -1):

We start with multiple scenes in our storyboard.

[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQyvL.png)

1. Create new view controller file
   Create new swift file
   For our custom view controller

[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex3Pl.png)

2. Setup file
   In our new file,
   Type in code
   To set up class structure

[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDKR4.png)

3. link file to view controller in Storyboard
   In Storyboard,
   Click on our view controller

[pic a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3At1.png)

[pic b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyGhI.png)

[pic c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpadv.png)

In the Identity Inspector,
In the Class field,
Type in the name of the new view controller file we created in step 1

4. open Assistant view

[see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdlVH.png)

5. Done!
   We are ready to write code
   In our view controller
   That is connected to our view controller in the Storyboard

[see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPsaY.png)